# Inserting a hashbyte value into a table via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, hash

I have created a table with `username`,`password`,`hashvalue` as columns.

```
create table userDetails
(
username varchar(50),
password varchar (50),
hashvalue varchar (3000)
)
```

I want to have each password stored in the table to be hashed by executing a stored procedure and in the same stored procedure, the hashed value is inserted into the table.

I created the stored procedure as follows :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hashpwd
@username   varchar(50)     = default ,
@pwd        varchar(50)      = default

AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @hashed varchar(4000);
SET @hashed = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @pwd);  --edited to @pwd 
select username,password from userDetails
WHERE username LIKE @username AND password LIKE @pwd;
END

BEGIN
insert into userDetails 
(hashvalue) values (@hashed);
END
```

The procedure can be executed, but the result is wrong. It produces NULL and a random string of characters. A 3rd row was also created when there are only 2 rows in the table initially.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You're hashing the wrong variable. And the code logic is wrong. I'm not sure whether these are new users - if they ARE, you need to also specify the username column when inserting

Comment: oh yes, I didn't spot the mistake. Thanks. Hmm I planning to execute the SP in such a way that it reads each password from the table and hashes each of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create PROCEDURE hashpwd
@username   varchar(50)     = default ,
@pwd        varchar(50)      = default

AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @hashed varchar(4000);
SET @hashed = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @pwd); --(@pwd instead of @hashed)
Update userDetails set hashvalue = @hashed
WHERE username LIKE @username AND password LIKE @pwd
END
```

You should use Update statement instead of Insert and statement should appear with in the procedure body.

Comment: thanks for the tip on Update, but it still doesn't work. 0 rows affected.

Comment: You should try to understand what has been done and update as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting an error when submitting my response, but for the previous response above, replace the where clause with this

```
WHERE username = @username
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the wrong results is due to the data type for your `hashvalue` column. As the `HASHBYTES` function returns `VARBINARY`, you should use this as your data type.

```
create table userDetails
(
username varchar(50),
password varchar (50),
hashvalue varbinary(40) -- Note, this should only be 40 characters long
)
```

I'm not really sure what youre stored procedure is meant to do. I would imagine that for a given username & password, you want to update the hashvalue on the corresponding row? If so, I would do this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hashpwd
@username   varchar(50)     = default ,
@pwd        varchar(50)      = default

AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE userDetails
    SET hashvalue = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @pwd);  --edited to @pwd 
    WHERE username LIKE @username AND password LIKE @pwd;
END
```